# Getting the signature for upload to Amazon S3 using AngularJS cryptograph and CryptoJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, amazon-s3

I want to upload images to my Amazon S3 bucket using this tutorial

http://coenraets.org/blog/2013/09/how-to-upload-pictures-from-a-phonegap-app-to-amazon-s3/

This is the github repo https://github.com/ccoenraets/phonegap-s3-upload/blob/master/client/phonegap-s3-upload/www/s3uploader-unsecured.js

but this was done using nodejs now i want to recreate it using AngularJS but i have one issue.

In his code, he got the signature like this

```
var crypto = require('crypto')
signature = crypto.createHmac('sha1', secret).update(policyBase64).digest('base64');
```

But in AngularJS i am using 
https://github.com/sytelus/CryptoJS and https://github.com/middleout/angular-cryptography

And as such i cant do it the way they have done it, does anyone have a clue how i can rewrite just that line of code in AngularJS using these two libs or even one they have used before?

Thanks

Comment: Wait... Are you trying to get the signature on the client-side? That is a very BAD idea (you'd have to expose your secret key in the source code, so everyone can see it)

Comment: i want the code to work first then i can make it safer.

Comment: There's no way you can make it safer. You must NOT do this on the client. Do that on a server and then request the authorization with an AJAX request.

Comment: mehn dude i need my code to work first then i can create a service and do it on d server or make it safer but first i need to solve my issue first. Anywys i have found a solution for my problem, it is fixed.